# TypeError: Cannot read property '_csrf' of undefined

Tags: express

I'm getting CSRF token errors..

`TypeError: Cannot read property '_csrf' of undefined at Object.handle (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:45:28) at next (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15) at Object.session [as handle] (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:221:66) at next (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15) at Object.cookieParser [as handle] (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js:60:5) at next (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15) at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:37:5) at next (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15) at Object.expressValidator [as handle] (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:148:10) at next (/home/nodejs/sites/IcoderStuff/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)`

## Packages ( packages.json )

```
"express": "3.0.3",
"less-middleware": "0.1.12",
"hbs": "2.3.0",
"express-validator": "0.4.1",
"mongoose" : "3.x",
"node-uuid" : "1.x",
"request" : "2.x",
"async" : "0.2.x",
"date-utils": "1.x",
"jade": "0.31.2",
"xml2js" : "0.2.7",
"MD5" : "1.0.3",
"csv" : "0.3.3",
"nodemailer" : "0.4.4"
```

## Server.js

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
  app.set('views', __dirname);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(expressValidator);
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'xkvnjiersape', store: store }));
  app.use(express.csrf());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));  
  app.use(require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet);
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Comment: I don't have idea why but here is the reason why I got this error: if you put cookieParser after `csrf` plugin it gives the same error.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps this will help someone else, not sure if it was the same cause for me as for the OP. However this problem appeared to me after restarting my computer, and after embarrassingly long time I figured out that it was because Redis (I used connect-redis as session store) didn't restart automatically.

In other words it seems that `TypeError: Cannot read property '_csrfSecret' of undefined` or `csrf of undefined` occurs when the session store is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andreas. I had the exact same problem.  Shutdown redis on friday and forgot to start it up on monday.

Comment: Yep can't believe I got burned by this yet again!! -_-  Thanks Andreas.  I'm baking an error message into Sails to catch this case.

Comment: Great answer. I was doing the same and asking for the `csrf` token before setting up the `cokie-parser`